# Acknowledgments in flow control protocol

Tags: networking, flow-control

[image]

Can someone explain it to me as to why in selective repeat it's not possible for an acknowledgment to come for a packet that falls outside the current window? Because it may be possible that there is some delayed acknowledgment. It's possible in all sliding window protocols then why is statement 2 only true?

Moreover, in the solution, they mentioned that statement 2 is true because GBN has cumulative ack because of which if we receive ack 2 then the sender will assume that both packets 1 and 2 have been received successfully and so it slides the window to remove 1 and 2 from it but later we might get ack 1 which I feel is not possible because here we are talking about cumulative ack not independent.
So how is this reason valid?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the back. Cummulative acknowledgments do not imply that there are delayed acknowledgements. GoBackN can in theory not acknowledge every single packet, but this is an optimization of practical protocols. So, I would assume, that GoBackN acknowledges every single packet.

Assuming that GoBackN acknowledges every single packet, the situation you are describing can happen. The receiver has received all packets in order, and send ACKs to every single packet in order. The channel however does not guaranty (reliable) in order delivery, i.e., the ACKs can arrive in arbitrary order. If two ACKs were reordered, exactly what they describe will happen.

In selective repeat each packet acknowledges only the packet received. And this only happens if the packet was sent. And the packet can only be sent as a part of sender window. Also, since ACKs are not cummulative, if the ACK for the second packet in the window is received first, the window will not move (since first packet is not acknowledged).

**edit** Actually, what could happen in selective repeat is following. Sender sends a packet, and receives no ACK. Then the timer fires, and the packet is retransmitted. And after the timer has fired, the first ACK has arrived. The window moves. Then, some time after the second ACK arrives, and it is outside the window. This can happen if the timer is set incorrectly, or if the ACK spent too much time somewhere in transit (which should be covered by the channel model). So, I guess you are correct, saying that it is possible.

Also, delayed ACKs usually refer to a TCP receiver, that does not acknowledge every received packet, but instead sends a single ACK for several of them. With cummulative acknowledgements this works trivially, since ACK for every single packet is not required. I don't see any way to implement delay acknowledgements for selective repeat, expect send 2 acks in the same packet, but then these ACKs will be for packets inside a window.